# Security of .env file (enviromental variables) in React JS App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, environment-variables

I heard that .env file was for securing variables (like API keys) in front-end, but then I read that enviromental variables are embedded in the build.
So, what are the enviromental variables, for example, in React?

Comment: your credentials are certainly not embedded in the build,

Comment: React is a rendering library, it does not care about where any data comes from.

Comment: Both the front end and the back end can have environment variables. Things like private keys that shouldn't be shared should not be in the front end environment file. They can be in the back end one, since the public doesn't have access to that

Comment: So if it isn't secure, .env file in front-end is for having variables globally and access them from anywhere?

Comment: ".env file in front-end" --- this statement needs clarification. There is no special properties in `.env`, it's just a text file, _like any other text file_.

Comment: can hacker read .env file, when extract android build?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but people are still arguing in 2022.
Just reiterating what Jayce444 stated, because he knows what he's talking about.

React JS is a Frontend technology.
Do NOT place your API keys in your react app's .env file.
They WILL be visible to anyone who inspects your app.

Instead, you can create a backend app with an api for your front end app.
Any requests like logging in, or database interactions, send from your front-end to the back-end app.
It's a bit of extra work, but this is how you secure it.
Also, if you plan to easily port your react app to a react-native app,
you'll need the backend api to support multi-platform apps anyway!

Here is a guide that helped me with examples.
https://youtu.be/yICiz12SdI4
The guy isn't the best at explaining and Passport is currently experiencing some bugs with their version (at the time of writing this) and cookie-sessions, but I was able to trouble shoot through them.

Hope this helps!
Doing something like this is probably one of the best projects to have in a portfolio for web dev.